# Flutter Add page specific app bar actions

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

So i have a main page with scaffold, app bar and drawer. My question is is there a way to add specific app bar actions from the child pages? Or do i have to add them all and conditionally show/hide them on the main page?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you should use one `Scaffold()` for each page and you should not nest Scaffolds.

Inside your `Scaffold()` you have your `AppBar()`.
So you can control each page appbar actions with no problem.

What I mean is that each page, has this kind of code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: MyDrawer(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("your screen title"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.security),
            onPressed: () { print("icon pressed"); },
          ),
        ],
      body: Container(),
    );
  }
```